# How to sort an integer array on lexicological order using only adjacent swaps for a given max # of swaps(m)

Tags: algorithm

I was asked that one during a phone interview of course, the other questions where fine, but that one I'm still not sure of the *best* answer.

At first i thought it smelled of a radix sort but since you can't only use adjacent swaps of course not.

So I think it's more of a bubble sort type algo, which is what I tried to do but the "max number of swaps" bit makes it very tricky (along with he lexicological part but i guess that's just a comparaison side issue)

I guess my algo would be something like (of course now i have better ideas than during the interview !)

```
int index = 0;
while(swapsLeft>0 && index < arrays.length)
{
  int smallestIndex = index;
  for(int i=index; i < index + swapsLeft)
  {
    // of course < is not correct, we need to compare as string or "by radix" or something
    if(array[i]) < array[smallestIndex]
       smallestIndex = i; 
  }
  // if found a smaller item within swap range then swap it to the front
  for(int i = smallestIndex; i > index; i--)
  {
    temp = array[smallestIndex]; 
    array[smallestIndex] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp
    swapsLeft--;
  }
  // continue for next item in array
  index ++; // edit:could probably optimize to index = index + 1 + (smallestIndex - index) ?
}
```

Does that seem about right ?

Who as a better solution, I'm curious as to an efficient / proper way to do this.

Comment: For a [sic] "lexicological" sort, I would think you'd first have to convert the integers to strings (based on their names?) so you would have an alphabet to sort by.  English lexical order sort of 1..10 is: eight, five, four, nine, one, seven, six, ten, three, two...

Comment: Thanks Chis, I agree on that. I think either convert to string or have a function that looks at the number radix by radix(probably more efficient). I'm more concerned about the most efficient swap piece of the algo though.

Comment: Juts realize i could do an optimization in there. when i swap/buble an item by several spots toward the front i could probably move forward by that much in the array since that part would have got sorted already.

Comment: This question sounds like complete non-sense ... maybe this is the thing to find out :-)

Comment: @coproc ... I think it makes sense but I think it's worded to make you panic "too much !" ... sadly that worked and I didn't do well during the interview, kinda chased my own tail for a while. Of course within 10mn of hanging the phone I mostly figured it out. Also the dev asking the question had a very very though accent so that did not help either :-/

Answer (score 0):

I am actually working on writing this exact code for my Algorithms class in Java for my Software Engineering Bachelors degree. So I will help you solve this by explaining the problem, and the steps to solve it. You are going to need at least 2 methods to do this more than once.

First you take your first value, just to make this easy lets keep it small and simple.

1 2 3 4

You should be using an array for sorting. To find the next number lexologically, you start out on the far right, move to the left, and stop when you find your first decrease. You have to replace that smaller value with the next largest value on the right. So for our example we would be replacing 3 with 4. So our next number is:

1 2 4 3

That was pretty simple right? Don't worry it gets much harder. Let's now try to get the next number using:

1 4 3 2

Ok so we start out on the far right and move left till our first smaller number. 2 is smaller than 3 is smaller than 4 is larger than 1. Ok so we have our first decrease at 1. So now we need to move back to the right till we hit the last number that is larger than 1. 4 is larger than 1, 3 is larger than 1, and 2 is larger than 1. Ok with 2 being the last number that means that 2 need to replace 1. But what about the rest of the numbers, well they are already in order, they are just backwards of what we need. So we need to flip the order and we come up with:

2 1 3 4

So you need a method that does that sorting, and another method that calls that method in a loop until you have done the correct number of parameters.